# Kafka - Why fresh groupId doesn't return all messages in topic when setting AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG as "latest"

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

I try to implement a very simple Kafka (0.9.0.1) consumer in scala (code below).

For my understanding, Kafka (or better say the Zookeeper) stores for each groupId the offset of the last consumed message for a giving topic. So given the following scenario:

1. Consumer with `groupId1` which Yesterday consumed the only 5
   messages in a topic. Now last consumed message has offset 4 (considering the 
   first message with offset 0)
2. During the night 2 new messages arrive to the topic
3. Today I restart the consumer, with the same `groupId1`, there will
   be two options:

Option 1: The consumer will read the last 2 new messages which arrived during the night if I set the following property as `"latest"`:

```
props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest")
```

Option 2: The consumer will read all the 7 messages in the topic if I set the following property as `"earliest"`:

```
props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest")
```

**Problem:** For some reason, if I change the groupId of the consumer to `groupId2`, that is a new groupId for the given topic, so it never consumed any message before and its latest offset should be 0. I was expecting that by setting

```
props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest")
```

The consumer will read during the first execution all the messages stored in the topic (the equivalent of having earliest). And then for following executions it will consume just the new ones. However this is not what happens.

If I set a new `groupId` and keep `AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG` as `latest`, the consumer is not able to read any message. What I need to do then is for the first run set `AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG` as `earliest`, and once there is already an offset different to 0 for the groupID I can move to `latest`.

Is this how it should be working my consumer? Is there a better solution than switching the `AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG`after the first time I run the consumer?

Below is the code I am using as a simple consumer:

```
class KafkaTestings {

  val brokers = "listOfBrokers"
  val groupId = "anyGroupId"
  val topic = "anyTopic"

  val props = createConsumerConfig(brokers, groupId)

  def createConsumerConfig(brokers: String, groupId: String): Properties = {
    val props = new Properties()
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, brokers)
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId)
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "true")
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "1000")
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "30000")
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "12321")
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest")
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
    props
  }

  def run() = {
    consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(this.topic))

    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor.execute(    new Runnable {
      override def run(): Unit = {

        while (true) {
          val records = consumer.poll(1000)

          for (record <- records) {
            println("Record: "+record.value)
          }

        }

      }
    })
  }
}

object ScalaConsumer extends App {
  val testConsumer = new KafkaTestings()
  testConsumer.run()
}
```

[This](https://www.programcreek.com/scala/kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer) was used as a reference to write this simple consumer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is working as documented.

If you start a new consumer group (i.e. one for which there are no existing offsets stored in Kafka), you have to choose if the consumer should be starting from the EARLIEST possible messages (the oldest message still available in the topic) or from the LATEST (only messages that produced from now on).

> Is there a better solution than switching the AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG after the first time I run the consumer?

You can keep it at EARLIEST, because the second time you run the consumer, it will already have stored offsets and just pick up there. The reset policy is only used when a new consumer group is created.

> Today I restart the consumer, with the same groupId1, there will be two options:

Not really. Since the consumer group was running the day before, it will find its committed offsets and just pick up where it left off. So no matter what you set the reset policy to, it will get these two new messages.

---

By aware though, that Kafka does not store these offsets forever, I believe the default is just a week. So if you shut down your consumers for more than that, the offsets may be aged out, and you could run into an accidental reset to EARLIEST (which may be expensive for large topics). Given that, it is probably prudent to change it to LATEST anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, very informative. So my conclusion from your answer is: the earliest will pick up all offsets in the first run, and all new messages from the following runs. Which is actually the perfect behaviour, since not parameter change required. BUT, it is risky in case the offsets may be aged out, so to don't be worried about that scenario, what I understand the best is to make an initial run with earliest and from following runs move the parameter to latest. Am I right?

Comment: Depends on what is worse for you: re-processing (potentially a lot of) data, or missing out on data that is in the topic but that you skip during the reset.  Ideally, don't lose those offsets...

Comment: But As I understand it is possible to avoid both scenarios by switching the parameter isn't? I mean if we use earliest for first run, to read everything is already in the topic, and from the second run we set the parameter to latest, there is not risk of reprocessing and we will not miss the initial messages neither. Or am I missing something

Comment: If you keep the consumer running all the time, yes. If you shut it down for a week, your offsets may be lost (this is configurable somewhere).

Answer (score 0):

> You can keep it at EARLIEST, because the second time you run the consumer, it will already have stored offsets and just pick up there. The reset policy is only used when a new consumer group is created.

In my testing, I often want to read from the earliest offset, but as noted, once you've read messages with a given groupId, then your offset remains at that pointer. 
I do this:

`properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, UUID.randomUUID());`